# How to Convert Binary Data to Zip file?

Tags: java, android, zip, binary-data

Right now I am working on a task to convert binary data in to a zip file

I am calling a url and getting  a response from server like

A@B�ArE⏾�7�ϫ���f�걺N�����Yg���o_M^�D�T�U X_���e?� hi\  `� �ڂ(� �0 rm��'�ed���� �:6h�k�ڗ� ���fnp���7��)��:��N�U�viR�,) II����M`��Np�M��7��
n��
!A!)  )AAFAq)Q)�y
  y� ��.�����?���
��֞��ͅ��Ɲ_�O�����nc��f��w��ʰ�6��3 2�ƢZZ��N0� O{� mC� ��$��,>����������
���CW/)?�?٥��ߗ�d�=�R�J*E{2L���ח�W���ӑ_PRR�_@�_H��:������Ə�Ջ�J�^v�0wo��+�o���
�-Ä@�R6��P�(���0�WPj�k�
C�E

now I want to save this data to zip file i have searched a lot and find some links but not meet the goal.

here i have done

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(
     "products.zip", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
   osw.write(data);
   osw.close();
```

please guid me if you have any idea about this.

Comment: Are the data already in a zip format? If not use a [ZipOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html).

Comment: no it's not in zip format

Comment: what if it is in zip format ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757545/how-to-save-zip-file-represented-as-a-string-in-node-js

Comment: @DEVELOPER May be binary data

Comment: @SmitPatel could you please point an example or something. Thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I need to do is construct a BufferedInputStream from the entity. Just replace BufferedReader with a BufferedInputStream. I would recommend  using ISO-8859-1 .An underlying streaming encoder to read binary data is a waste of processing power.

```
private class methodName extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, byte[]> {

        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            String uri = params[0];
            try {

                MultipartEntityBuilder entity;
                File f;
                FileBody fb;
                entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

                entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                f = new File(zipImageFile);
                fb = new FileBody(f);
                entity.addPart("orderFile", fb);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
                Log.e("Uploload Missing Image URL", "" + uri);
                httppost.setEntity(entity.build());
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //              byte[] fileBites=null;
               BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
               ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[5 * 1024];
                int numRead = -1;
                while( (numRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer))!= -1)
                {
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                }
                byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
                byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                byte[] result = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    //              fileBites=stringBuffer.toString().getBytes();
    //              Log.e("FILE BITES", fileBites+"=>"+fileBites.length);



                return ;

    //              return stringBuffer.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.toString().getBytes();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(byte[] result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.e("Response From Server", "" + result);
            writeToFile(result);

        }

    }


    private void writeToFile(byte[] data) {
        try {

            FileOutputStream fop = null;
            File file;

            file = new File(AppConstants.DataPath+"/products.zip");
            fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            try {            
            fop.write(data);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
        unzipImage(AppConstants.DataPath + "/products.zip",
                AppConstants.DataPath);
    }catch (Exception E)
    {

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> OutputStreamWriter osw

NO!

A `Writer` is made to write *text*, not binary.

In the first place, it looks like you *read* text as well, which you shouldn't.

Use an `InputStream` to read the original content, and an `OutputStream` to write into the file:

```
final OutputStream out = /* open your file using a FileOutputStream here */;

final byte[] buf = new byte[8096]; // size as appropriate

// "in" is the InputStream from the socket
int count;

try {
    while ((count = in.read(buf)) != -1)
        out.write(buf, 0, count);

    out.flush();
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Readers are not meant to read octet streams.

Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.

You're looking for a BufferedInputStream.

The getContent() method on the HttpEntity returns an InputStream. Wrap this around a BufferedInputStream and write it to a file or a ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[5 * 1024];
    int numRead = -1;
    while( (numRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer))!= -1)
    {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
    }
    byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    byte[] result = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

To save on memory I'd advise you to write to a BufferedOutputStream instead of trying to get the bytes from the stream into a data structure. The android device is likely to run out of memory for large zip files.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to avoid the trouble of converting Binary by adding options to your request.

In `NodeJS` I specify the responseType as `arraybuffer`

```
const res = await axios.get('/routToThat/file', {
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/zip',
  },
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
});
```

So instead of receiving the server response as a Binary string:

```
A@B�ArE⏾�7�ϫ���f�걺N�����Yg���o_M^�D�T�U X_���e?� hi\...
```

I get a Buffer:

```
Buffer(22781691) [80, 75, 3, …]
```

**NOTE**: In my case the response I get is already a ZIP file.

More details on this `NodeJS` answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62460311/3645464