# zip file that already saved in Sql table as binary

Tags: sql-server

I have a zip file that already saved in Sql table as binary I need to read the contents of this record in the database

Comment: You should add more info to your question. For example, show the code that inserted the record in the db + the db structure.

Comment: then why dont you ?

Comment: I have table BenaireZip (BinZip varbinary, Code int), in BinZip I have contents the zip but in the binary I need to read it

Answer (score 1):

check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778509/how-to-convert-binary-data-to-zip-file)

There are many ways to do it other than this too, depending on the framework you use